# ошибка sun.applet.AppletViewer

Tags: java, html, eclipse, applet

При запуске Java апплета через Run > Run As > Java Applet, выдает такую ошибку

```
Error: Could not find or load main class sun.applet.AppletViewer   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.applet.AppletViewer
```

[image: ошишбка]

код Java:

```
public class HelloApplet extends java.applet.Applet{ public void paint(java.awt.Graphics graphics)
{
    graphics.drawString("Привет, мир!", 70, 40);
} }
```

[image: jaav код]

код HTML:

[image: html код]

библиотека с файлами :

[image: файлы]

я уже пробовал обновить java, мне это не помогло...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После обновления до Java 7 Update 65 апплеты перестали запускаться.
https://www.java.com/ru/download/help/java7u65_applet_loading.xml